# Why Binary language is used as a first language for the Computer Systems not a high level Language?

Tags: software

--> why computers not used high level language as a first Language what are the main reasons?

Answer (score 1):

In (very) short : Because basically a computer is composed of multiple electronic devices that consistently switch between two states (see transistors). For a human, this can be idealized by a state 0 or a state 1 from which the binary is derived. This is the core language, close to processor instructions, only then appears low-level languages and high level languages that provide more abstraction level.